# bootstrap not showing tooltip

Tags: css, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap

I followed bootstrap main page examples to setup some tooltips in my page but they doesn't works.
i tryed just this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var options ;
        $('.tip').tooltip();
    </script>

    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" class="tip" title="first tooltip" data-original-title="Logout">
```

why does it doesn't works and doesn't show me any console error? i'm using latest boostrap version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should either move the script below the HTML it references or wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tip').tooltip();
});
```

To ensure that the DOM has been loaded before you call the tooltip() method.